# Iterating over a 2D array

Tags: javascript, json

Here is a JSON object:

```
 {
    "status": "OK", 
    "user": {
        "auth_token": "xxxxxx", 
        "name": "John Dot", 
        "pictures":["http://xxxxx.com/me/picture"],
        "nickname":"tg",
        "yob": "1986",

    }
}

var PJson = JSON.stringify(this.responseText);
PJson = JSON.parse(PJson);
```

I am only interested in getting the keys and values in the user object. I tried a for each loop:

```
for (var key in PJson.user) {

        console.log('here');
                     console.log(key);

}
```

Didn't work. Not sure why, any idea why - cheers.

Comment: What do you mean "Didn't work"?  Was there an error?  Is everything undefined?

Comment: it will complain that the .user is undefined - sorry

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Can you create an example on JSFiddle?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(this.responseText)` doesn't do what you think it does.  You are calling `stringify` on what is *already* a string!  I assume you meant `JSON.parse(this.responseText)` and the `JSON.stringify` was just a mistake.

Comment: Sigh, tried it in JSFiddle, actually works. http://jsfiddle.net/dnq3c/4/.

BUT the problem is if I dont do stringify , I get an array back, instead of a JSON object. So I need to convert the array into a string (as it's structured in the API) and then parse that into a json object for it to be a json object to begin with

Comment: after using typeof , turns out json.parse is not turning my string into a jsonobject

Comment: @bobo2000: There's no such thing as a JSON object.  It works in the JSFiddle because `testJson` isn't JSON.  It's a JavaScript object literal.  JSON is a *string representation* of data.  If it's not a string, it's not JSON.